# comparing string values

Tags: android, string

I want to compare 2 strings.
My first value is in 'list[0][0]' variable and the second value is in item[0].
But when I am comparing the 2 strings using 'if' statement, I don't get the answer.

if(selected_list[0][0]==items[0])
{
// some code
}
it is not working.
But when I am hard-coded these values, it is working fine.
if("banana"=="banana")
{
// some code
}
Please give me the solution? 
Thank you..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00001.shtml) is an explanation of how strings should be compared and the different options for doing so.  They aren't as simple as comparing int's.

```
if (string1.equals(string2))
```

Comment: Just to add for Java beginners, it is done this way because Strings are *Objects*.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare it as `[list[0][0] isEqualToString:items[0]]` otherwise you are comparing their addresses not the values.

Comment: Wouldn't that apply to iPhone development??

Comment: Oops, wrong language, but it works the same way anyway. Just the way to write it is different (list[0][0]).equals(items[0])

Answer (score 1):

Use the compareTo() or equals() method of one of your strings, passing the other string as argument.

```
string1.equals(string2)
// returns true if both strings are equal

string1.compareTo(string2)
// returns 0 if both strings are equal
```